# Android: connecting to USB device, wait for permission

Tags: java, android, permissions, usb

I'm trying to do this: connect to USB device and get the opened (or failed) connection. I did the logic according to examples and explanations that I have found, but I have problem with waiting for permission grant. First I tried a "good" way of using wait()+notifyAll(), than I tried straightforward loop with checks, but both times the waiting method (waitConnection()) was blocking for the timeout I gave it, and only after that the message was received. So I tried these 2 versions.

1. wait/notifyAll:

   ```
   public UsbConnector startConnection(Context context) {

   BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           String action = intent.getAction();
           if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION.equals(action)) {
               synchronized (syncObj) {
                   if (intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)) {
                       UsbDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                       if (device != null) {
                           if (device.getVendorId() == vendorId && device.getProductId() == productId) {
                               connection = usbManager.openDevice(device);
                               connectedDevice = device;
                           }
                       }
                   }
                   syncObj.notyfyAll();
               }
           }
       }
   };

   try {
       usbManager = (UsbManager) context.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
       for (final UsbDevice device : usbManager.getDeviceList().values()) {
           if (device.getVendorId() == this.vendorId && device.getProductId() == this.productId) {

               context.registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION));
               usbManager.requestPermission(device,
                       PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0));
               break;
           }
       }
   } catch (Exception e) {
   }
   return this;
   }

   public UsbDeviceConnection waitConnection(int timeout) {
   try {
       Thread.sleep(10, 0);
       syncObj.wait(timeout);
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
   }
   return getConnection();
   }
   ```
2. straightforward loop

   ```
   public UsbConnector startConnection(Context context) {

   BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           String action = intent.getAction();
           if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION.equals(action)) {
               synchronized (this) {
                   if (intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)) {
                       UsbDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                       if (device != null) {
                           if (device.getVendorId() == vendorId && device.getProductId() == productId) {
                               connection = usbManager.openDevice(device);
                               connectedDevice = device;
                           }
                       }
                   }
                   permissionRequested = false;
               }
           }
       }
   };

   try {
       permissionRequested = false;
       usbManager = (UsbManager) context.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
       for (final UsbDevice device : usbManager.getDeviceList().values()) {
           if (device.getVendorId() == this.vendorId && device.getProductId() == this.productId) {

               permissionRequested = true;
               context.registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION));
               usbManager.requestPermission(device,
                       PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0));
               break;
           }
       }
   } catch (Exception e) {
   }
   return this;
   }

   public UsbDeviceConnection waitConnection(int timeout) {
   int waited = timeout;
   while (permissionRequested && waited > 0) {
       try {
           Thread.sleep(10, 0);
       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
       }
       waited -= 10;
   }

   return getConnection();
   }
   ```

So in both cases, according to logs, the waitConnection() method (that is called by the consumer immediately after startConnection()) seems to block the execution (I gave it timeout 10 seconds, and it was blocked for 10 seconds), and only right after it's completed, the BroadcastReceiver gets the message. It appears that requestPermission() is not async (as I thought it is), but in this case, how is it possible that startConnection() exits immediately and before the message is received? And how can I wait for BroadcastReceiver to get the message? Say if I don't use the waitConnection() method, how my consumer should know the moment when it can start checking for connection availability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"and only right after it's completed, the BroadcastReceiver gets the message"

The `onReceived` callback, by default, is called on the main thread.  It sounds like you are calling `waitConnection()` on the main thread as well.  Since `waitConnection()` blocks, the main thread cannot process any additional messages until `waitConnection()` returns.  This means that `onReceived` will not be called until `waitConnection()` times out.

It is generally a bad idea to block the main thread.  [Read here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads)

Instead, you could have `onReceive` launch a new activity which then does whatever it is you need to do once you get USB permission.  That may or may not be the best solution for you, but regardless, the key here is to never block the main thread.

Comment: I see, so I tried to run that "startConnection" block as AsyncTask, but the result was the same. Is there some special magic forcing "onReceived" to always run in the main thread? But when you write "by defalt" - do you mean that there is still a way to make it executed in paralel thread?

Comment: I'm thinking that maybe I can start connecting in one activity (the one that is not concerned with USB at all, but it just comes before), and than use the connection in the next, the one that actually needs it... I will have to pass the connection and all the objects somehow, and this will look very strange, but I hope it will work. And I'm once again admired by Java's ability to make simple things complex. :)

Comment: Its `waitConnection`, not `startConnection`, that would benefit from being run in an AsyncTask, since `waitConnection` is the one blocking.  `onReceive` can be configured to execute on a different thread; you'll need to pass a `Handler` in the `BroadcastReceiver` constructor.

Comment: @Kurtevich correction, you need to pass a `Handler` into `registerReceiver`